# convert to upper case in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting syntax errors, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong

```py
sentence = "Especially in electronic communications, writing in all caps is equivalent to yelling."

result = sentence.upper()
print =(result)
```

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: what do you think should happen when you do `print = (result)`?

Comment: There is no `SyntaxError` in that code snippet.  Perhaps you are using Python 2.7 where print is a statement?  Either way, that's not how you print.  In Python 3 do `print(result)` and in Python 2.7 do `print result`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski No, I'm using 3.10

Comment: change `print =(result)` to `print(result)`.

Comment: @matszwecja i guess it should print the sentence but all in upper case

Comment: @Code-Apprentice:  That's correct, but the OP's code doesn't produce a `SyntaxError` so I'm a bit perplexed.  There's some missing code here.

Comment: ```print(result)```

Comment: @Reyan-droid Well, no, you would assign a value of result to variable called `print`. As I'm 99% sure it's not what you want to do, you should use `print(result)` or `print result` depending on whether you are using Python 2 or 3. And since you tagged both, we can't really tell which one it is supposed to be. Please only use the one that actually matters.

Comment: @Reyan-droid are you **sure** that you are using Python 3.10? You do not get a Syntax Error from that piece of code in Python 3

Comment: yes, I'm sure, just checked it again

Comment: @Reyan-droid: The code you posted is not the code that produced the error.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

hey hi you have used "=" sign after print statement that's why its showing there's an error. Don't use the "=" sign.. just use "print(result)"

Comment: `print =(result)` is valid Python, so it doesn't explain the error. (No doubt that's what the OP needs, but perhaps there's a `SyntaxError` lurking elsewhere in the code.)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski it is valid Python3, it is not valid in Python2.

Comment: @matszwecja: I believe you missed the OP's comment where he clarified "No, I'm using 3.10." And probably missed my comment where I wrote "There is no SyntaxError in that code snippet. Perhaps you are using Python 2.7 where print is a statement? Either way, that's not how you print. In Python 3 do `print(result)` and in Python 2.7 do `print result`"

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error ,You can simply write code as :

```
sentence = "Especially in electronic communications, writing in all caps is equivalent to yelling."
result = sentence.upper()
print(result)
```

No need to use = in the last line